# Averaging lengths and distances

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

A natural way in which Finsler metrics appear in Riemannian geometry is as averages of Riemannian metrics (e.g., the average of the arc-length elements
$\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$ and $\sqrt{2dx^2 + 3dy^2}$ is not the arc-length element of
a Riemannian metric on the plane). A simple application of this idea is the construction of a class of (Finsler) metrics in projective space for which geodesics are projective lines:

Consider the group $G$ of projective transformations on projective $n$-space and let $\mu$ be a compactly-supported Borel probability measure on $G$. 
Define the length of a curve $\gamma$ to be the expected value of the (canonical) length of the curve $T(\gamma)$, where $T \in G$.

**Claim.** The preceding construction defines a length structure on 
$\mathbb{R}P^n$ for which projective lines are geodesics.

This is essentially the same construction as in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119668/).

We can consider the following abstract version of this construction:

Consider a length space $(X,d)$ and a continuous group action $G \times X \rightarrow X$ of a locally compact topological group $G$ on the space $X$. If $\mu$ is a compactly-supported Borel probability measure on $G$, 
define the $\mu$-length of a curve $\gamma$ to be the expected value of the (canonical) length of the curve $T(\gamma)$, where $T \in G$, and define 
the $\mu$-distance between two points $x, y \in X$ as the expected value of 
$T \mapsto d(Tx,Ty)$.

**Questions.**

**1.** *Is the length of a curve in $(X,d_\mu)$ equal to its $\mu$-length?*

**2.** *When is $(X,d_\mu)$ a length space?*

**3.** *If $(X,d)$ is a Riemannian torus with distance function $d$, $G$ is also the torus acting on itself by translations, and $\mu$ is  the normalized Haar measure on $G$, is it true that $d_\mu$ the flat metric induced by the stable norm?*

Let me sketch why I think this last question may have a positive answer: a characterization of the stable norm by D. Burago states that if $d$ is a periodic length metric (the lift to $\mathbb{R}^n$ of a length metric 
on $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$), the stable norm is the unique norm satisfying
$$
\|x-y\| - C \leq d(x,y) \leq \|x-y\| + C
$$
for some constant $C > 0$ independent of $x$ and $y$. I hadn't noticed this before, but *the set of periodic metrics sharing the preceding inequality is a convex set.* Therefore, if an average of periodic length metrics with 
the same stable norm $\|\cdot\|$ is again a length metric, then the stable
norm this  average metric will again be $\|\cdot\|$. Averaging the metrics $d(x+z,y+z)$ as $z$ ranges over all points in the unit square should then yield a translation-invariant metric whose stable norm is $\|\cdot\|$. With some luck, this translation-invariant metric is induced by a norm and by Burago's theorem it would have to be the stable norm.

In any case, the above construction allows us to associate  a translation invariant metric to a periodic length metric,. The whole question is whether this metric comes from a norm or not.

**Disclaimer.** I *still* really haven't thought all these things through, but I thought it would be helpful to write them down to make things clearer (at least for myself) and perhaps someone here has already considered these averages. They are quite natural.

Comment: Just a comment on averaging: sums of intrinsic metrics are usually not intrinsic metrics (they are when, for example, they share the same geodesics).